# Perform report action "Go to report" in RDL file

Tags: reportingservices-2005, rdl

I want to perform **Report Action** on RDL file but without uploading RDL file to report server. Is there any way to set the report path of Local directory? I knew about below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-7-add-drillthrough-action-on-parent-report?view=sql-server-2017
But I want to set path of Local Directory in "Go to report".